# Use directive only if previous element is not disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-directive

Szenario:

I have an Inputfield like this

```
 <ion-input class="item item-input">
      <ion-label>Field</ion-label>
           <input type="text" ng-disabled="someCondition" model="somemodel" />
           <directive-element></directive-element>
 </ion-input>
```

Now I am using a directive to replace the "directive-element" with a button where I call a function on click, but i could not manage to detect if the input is disabled or not I already tried via `element[0]` to find it but no luck

```
.directive('directiveElement', function () {   
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: function (element, attrs) { 
             var input = ?????.
             if(input.disabled == false){             
                return "<button ng-click='myFunction()'></button>"; 
             }else{
                //DOnt show the button 
              }         
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.myFunction(){
                    //some logic
                }  


        };
    }

})
```

EDIT:

```
template: function (element, attrs) {
    if (element[0].previousElementSibling != null && element[0].previousElementSibling.tagName == 'INPUT' && element[0].previousElementSibling.disabled == true) {
          //this actually works kinda but somehow i still see the button...
    }
},
```

I wont use Jquery and If possible I would like to avoid Jqlite

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the condition and check it inside a third function:

```
template: function (element, attrs) {            
        return "<button ng-click='myConditionalFunction(someCondition)'></button>";             
},
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.myFunction(){
           //some logic
      } 

      scope.otherFunction(){
           //some other logic
      }  

      scope.myConditionalFunction(condition){
          if (condition) {
             scope.myFunction();
          } else {
             scope.otherFunction();
          }
      }

};
```

Comment: problem is this directive is used very often and the Condition is different for every single input so i would have to go through the whole project and change that, thats why i wanted to dynamically check the disabled attribute from the input

Comment: the problem is I actually want to hide the button if the input is disabled

Comment: If you want to hide it, use `ngHide`or `ngIf` :)

Comment: yes i know that but please tell me how do i get the disabled attribute from the input in the directive???

Comment: that is my real code i just left out the model names and conditions

Comment: That would be important in this case though! If the condition is tied to your model, as it seems, that would probably be the best way to get the value into the directive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105901/discussion-between-stackg91-and-luka-jacobowitz).